# Visual Studio Code hightlight tag

Tags: visual-studio-code

Please. How disabled mark tag ? Square around <>. If my coursor is before tag allways mark tag.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

### VSCode Highlight Matching Tag

**GitHub repository**: https://github.com/vincaslt/vscode-highlight-matching-tag

> This extension highlights matching opening and/or closing tags. Optionally it also shows path to tag in the status bar. Even though VSCode has some basic tag matching, it's just that - basic. This extension will try to match tags anywhere: from tag attributes, inside of strings, any files, while also providing extensive styling options to customize how tags are highlighted.

> Officially supported markup: HTML and JSX. Other flavors (XML, Vue, Angular, PHP) should work, but there are no guarantees. Feel free to report the issues on them anyway.

Result:

[image]

### [`MORE INFO VISIT`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag)

Using extension **highlight-matching-tag** and adding these settings

```
"highlight-matching-tag.style": {
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(63, 191, 63, 0.20)"
},
"editor.occurrencesHighlight": false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the settings.json file to disable the matching of the brackets on HTML files:

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.matchBrackets": "never"
}
```

But keep in mind, this disables also the bracket matching on **every** bracket (`()`, `[]`) inside HTML files.